# Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of sets such as $A_n=\{1, 2, 3,..., n\}$. Does $\mathbb{N} \in \{A_n\}$? How do you prove it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can I use the fact that $A_n=A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots \cup A_n$ and so it belongs to $\{A_n\}$ so if $A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n\cup \cdots= \mathbb{N}$ then $\mathbb{N}$ belongs to $\{A_n\}$

Comment: No, $\Bbb N$ is not an element of the set $\{A_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$.  Your set is the set of all *finite* subsets of the form $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ and contains no infinite sets.  Recall that $\infty$ is not an element of $\Bbb N$

Comment: Let $a_n=\frac1n$, then $\lim a_n=0$, is it true that $0=a_n$ for some $n$?

Answer (score 0):

You indeed have $\displaystyle \bigcup_n A_n = \mathbb N$.

So any element of $\mathbb N$ belongs to one of the $A_n$. **It doesn't mean that $\mathbb  N$ itself belongs to $\mathbb N$ or to one of the $A_n$.**

For a set $X$, $X \in X$ is not a tautology.

Comment: Then why the property that any union of subsets of {$A_n$}  belongs to {$A_n$} isn't true for a countable infinite union of members of the sequence?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by any union of subsets of $\{A_n\}$ belongs to $\{A_n\}$. A union for which indexes?